# How can I fix bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this bootstrap modal and I have two problems with it. One is minor and one is major.

1) (minor) My task is to show modal on the SECOND page (any SECOND PAGE) that person visits, but no matter how I hide it it still shows on the first page.

2) (Major!) It works incorrectly! That backdrop of the modal shows not matter whether it is on the page or not. This bug I tried to circumvent by using "display: none" in html on the backdrop. It works in chrome but not anywhere else.

How can I fix these issues?

My project is ye old, it uses bootstrap3 and jquery

```
`    <div class="modal fade signup-popup-modal" id="signUpPopUp" role="dialog" display="none">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" id="singUpPopUpDialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal__close" id="modalClose">
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body active" id="modalBodyStage-1">
                    <div class="body__discount-block">
                        <div class="discount-block__discount">
                            <p>
                                Subscribe to our emails &
                            </p>
                            <span>
                                <p>Get 15% off</p>
                            </span>
                            <p>
                                Your first order
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="discount-block__email">
                            <input id="emailSignup" type="email" name="signUp" placeholder="Input your email">
                            <button id="emailSignupSubmitButton" for="signUp">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="discount-block__text">
                            <p>
                                Plus you'll always be the first to know about exclusive offers and the latest trends.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="body__privacy">
                        <a href="#" id="modalPrivacyLink">Privacy Policy</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="modalBodyStage-2">
                    <form class="body__form">
                        <div class="form__text-block">
                            <h3>You're on the list.</h3>
                            <p>Thank you for joining us. Tell us more about yourself.
                            Use code: <span>welcome15</span> for 15% off your next purchase.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__credentials">
                            <input id="popupFirstName" type="text" name="firstName">
                            <input id="popupLastName" type="lastName">
                            <button class="credentials__button--save" id="firstLastNameSignupSubmitButton" type="button">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="body__privacy"><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body" id="modalBodyStage-3">
                    <h3>Thank you for successfully logging to our website!</h3>
                    <p>Get up to <span>15% off</span> your first order!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
```

LESS

```
    .signup-popup-modal {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 2500;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 0 !important;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;


  .modal-dialog {
    width: 690px;
    height: 325px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    z-index: 2400;

    .modal-content {
      background-image: url("../resources/images/Email_Pop_Up_image.jpg");
      background-size: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 5px;
      position: relative;

      @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        background-image: none;
        background-color: #dcdcdc;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .modal__close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 3rem;
        height: 3rem;
        border: 2px solid @white;
        border-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
                transform: translate(50%, -50%);
        background-color: @black;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
                align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
                justify-content: center;

        svg {
          font-size: 2rem;
          color: @white;
        }

        &:hover {
          cursor: pointer;

          svg {
            color: @secondaryBtnColor;
          }
        }
      }

      .modal-body,
      .modal-body#modalBodyStage-1 {
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
        display: none;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
                flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-box-pack: justify;
                justify-content: space-between;
        -webkit-box-align: start;
                align-items: flex-start;
        opacity: 1;

        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
          width: 100%;
        }

        .body__discount-block {
          height: 80%;
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: flex;
          -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
          -webkit-box-direction: normal;
                  flex-direction: column;
          -webkit-box-align: start;
                  align-items: flex-start;
          -webkit-box-pack: justify;
                  justify-content: space-between;

          @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            height: 82%;
            width: 90%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-left: 0 !important;
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
                    align-items: center;
          }

          @media screen and (max-width: 325px) {
            height: 82%;
            width: 98%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-left: 0 !important;
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
                    align-items: center;
          }


          .discount-block__discount {
            width: 75%;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: 500;
```

etc...

```
    define([
    'modules/jquery'
  ], function ($) {
    $("#signUpPopUp").modal('hide');
    $.cookie("SIGNED_USER", true, { path: '/'});
    if($.cookie("SIGNED_USER") && !$.cookie("EMAIL_SIGNUP_MODAL_DISSMISSED")) {
      $("#signUpPopUp").modal('show');
    } 
    $('#signUpPopUp').on('hidden.bs.modal', 
    function() {
      $.cookie("EMAIL_SIGNUP_MODAL_DISSMISSED", true, { path: '/', expires: 3});
    });
    $('#modalClose').click(function() {
      $("#signUpPopUp").modal('hide');
      $.cookie("EMAIL_SIGNUP_MODAL_DISSMISSED", true, { path: '/', expires: 3});
    });
    });
```

Comment: Why is your modal present in a page where its only purpose is to try to hide it ? Your backend should append it to your view when needed. You could use a session cookie for example.

Comment: Like how? My modal is hidden right from the start

Comment: Since i dont know your backend i can't tell you that. But usually its a bad idea to put stuff on your page that you will probably never use. It clutters the DOM and increases loading times. So my first step in solving this would be to ensure that the modal is only present on a page where it is actually needed.